# getElementByID for templateField TextBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have used RowDataBound for gridview. Below is my C# code

```
protected void gvParameterValue_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblLocID = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLocationID");
if(condition)
            {
                TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtValue");
                txtBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ValueOnChange();");
            }
        }
    }
```

Asp.Net code for gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvParameterValue" SkinID="GridView" runat="server" OnRowDataBound ="gvParameterValue_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Location Name">

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parameter Value">
            <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" SkinID="fineLineTextBox" TabIndex="1" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>    
                    <%--<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" SkinID="fineLineTextBox" TabIndex="1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="textBox1_textChanged"  AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPreDayVal" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PreviousValue") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate >
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

js function as below and i have a problem

```
function ValueOnChange()
     {

         var val = document.getElementById('lblPreDayValue').value;


   }
```

It gives error "`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required`"
i have tried all possible solutions from net but nothing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing `values` at the `RowBound` event of `gridview` , You are trying to access `getElementbyId('lblLocID')` is not going to work because it's id will be change when row renders .

```
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label lblLocID = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLocationID");
              Label lblPreDayValue =(Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPreDayValue");
            if (lblLocID.Text.Equals("154") || lblLocID.Text.Equals("168") || lblLocID.Text.Equals("178"))
            {
                TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtValue");
                txtBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ValueOnChange(" + lblPreDayValue.ClientID + ");");
            }
        }
```

After passing `ClientID` to function 
//Or you can directly pass the value of label and assign .

```
function ValueOnChange(ClntID)
     {

         var val = document.getElementById('ClntID').innerHTML;
     }
```

Comment: @Sagar Have you tried above code ? You can validate your entry during binding , However If you want to validate your `textbox` after binding try above code with  `AutoPostBack="true"` for `textbox` in interest.

Comment: it gives exception during run time...Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: All right friends, i think my code is not good i have to do more practice , but if anyone got answer please update it hear...

Comment: @Sagar Can you elaborate what actually you want , i mean requirement and if you can update your code with what you are doing now .

Comment: @Sagar At what `event` you are trying to `validate`  your `textbox` values ?Please if you can include that code in your post ,it may help.

Comment: actually i am using OnRowDataBound ="gvParameterValue_RowDataBound" in gridview.

Comment: In that event i am attaching onchange event to those text boxes as per condition in if. Now it works fine. As no data is binded to textbox i cant validate this data with data in label. So i have to validate that data at the time of values entering in text box.

Comment: sir i have tried above code but not worked it gives error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: how are you validating `textbox` values with `label` values ?? Please update your code and `javascript` function also .

Comment: as i dosent getting the ids of these text box and label how can i validate? thats my problem as i got these ids i will validate them.

Comment: ok i got ids of label and textbox. As i am new to this i dont know how to compare textbox value and label value. I am using following code                                                                   var txtValue = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].text;
        var lblValue = row.cells[2].childNodes[2].innerHTML;                                   if(txtvalue<lblvalue){//code here}                                                                but it does not going inside the if loop

Comment: why are you using `var` nothing wrong although using it ,See your compare operator here  `if(txtvalue<lblvalue)` what  values do they contain ? you are checking if `txtvalue` is greater than `lblvalue` than execute code , You sure you want that ? what is `txtvalue` it's a string ,int,double or what?

Comment: @Sagar Have you checked `lblvalue` and `txtvalue` are they alright? I mean post your values what are you comparing? You want to compare their length??if they are string or if it's int than it should work already , Please post your values in comment so things can be more clear .

Comment: Finally i got it. Thanks to all.After working on all code i got some solutions.OK friends thanks again for suggestions.  Keep it up...

Comment: @sagar let us know what was it .

Comment: function ValueOnChange(lnk){
        //debugger;
        
        var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
        
        var txtValue = row.cells[2].childNodes[0].value;
        var lblValue = row.cells[2].childNodes[2].innerHTML;
        var num1 = new Number(txtValue);
        var num2 = new Number(lblValue);
        if (lblValue == "") {
           //code hear
           
            
             row.cells[2].childNodes[0].focus();
        }
        if(num1<num2){
           
            row.cells[2].childNodes[0].focus();
        }
        
            }

Comment: lnk is parameter passed from txtBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ValueOnChange(this);");                                             now problem in focusing the textbox is their any other method other than focus().

Answer (score 2):

You've called `getElementById` on the ID `lblPreDayValue`. In your ASP.NET markup you've called it `lblPreDayVal`.

You might also want to use [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx) to ensure you get the correct ID generated by .NET

Comment: i have corrected lblPreDayValue to lblPreDayVal but still problem does not resolved.Is it required any extra coding. please help...Thanks RGraham...

Comment: @user2659305 The problem is that Asp.Net mangles Ids when outputting them - so you need to use the `ClientId()` function to get the mangled (real) id of an element

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the ClientID from the server-side during the binding step in the gvParameterValue_RowDataBound method like this :-

```
        TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtValue");
        Label lblVal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPreDayVal");
        txtBox.Attributes.Add("onchange", "ValueOnChange('" + lblVal.ClientID + "');");
```

And then inside the ValueOnChange method definition, pass the argument as cid (lets say).

```
function ValueOnChange(cid)
     {
         var val = document.getElementById(cid).innerHTML;
     }
```

Comment: This will resolve your problem in accessing the label value from the textbox field dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
function ValueOnChange()
     {
         var val = document.getElementById('#<%= lblPreDayVal.ClientID %>').innerHTML;
     }
```

If the above din work then

```
function ValueOnChange()
     {
         var val = document.getElementById('lblPreDayVal').innerHTML;
     }
```

Comment: Are you sure you added jquery file reference in aspx page..If yes then replace (.innerHtml) with (.Value).It should work..

Comment: i think i m using javascript then no need to add jquery.

Comment: Did you replace with .value

Comment: yes but not worked,my head is paining due to this, i have applied so many steps and so many suggestions from other forums also and confused with these.

Comment: See above code in rowdata bound i have attached onchange event to specific textboxes as per condition... means validation is done after rowdata bound event fired...

Comment: @user2659305 When your `gridview` binds with data , Your controls will be generated as per the numbers of rows and new `ID` will be assigned to them by suffixing `control name`(something like this `dgProgramSales$_ctl2$_ctl12`) with your ID (Check the `PageSource` for your label ID ) , Only way you can access any control using `ClintID` is during `RowBound` event .

Comment: @user2659305 Try `karan`  answer or mine .

Comment: suraj i have used ur answer but still gives "microsoft jscript runtime error object expected"

Comment: Actual problem is that... i am attaching onchange event to specific text boxes in row bound event. After that i am trying to validate this text box with lblpredayval label. i think that's why id is not founding.

Comment: The thing is suraj,Karan and myself, everyone provided all the easing possibilities to find a solution..Now its very clear,the mess is because of your unknown bad code,try to find that and fix it.remaining will work as if..

Comment: something is working. if i use id from html rendered coade. but i dont know how to traverse for all label values...

Comment: Can you explain briefly what is your requirement and post your code somewhere and share the link